# How to find the records when it comes first in the table, i have multiple such records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few columns, I am looking for a SQL query which can give me output with column 4 and 5 where I have value as 1 when value is seen for first time and when it comes again the value will be 0.

Hope I am not making question very complicated.

UniqueNameCount and UniqueDESCCount is the output I am looking at...

```
Inventory ID    Name    Description UniqueNameCount UniqueDESCCount
```

Expected results:

```
Inventory ID    Name    Description UniqueNameCount UniqueDESCCount
IN0001  Item 1  Desc 1  1   1
IN0002  Item 2  Desc 2  1   1
IN0003  Item 3  Desc 1  1   0
IN0004  Item 1  Desc 1  0   0
IN0005  Item 2  Desc 5  0   1
IN0006  Item 2  Desc 5  0   0
IN0007  Item 2  Desc 5  0   0
IN0008  Item 3  Desc 2  0   0
IN0009  Item 3  Desc 2  0   0
IN0010  Item 1  Desc 3  0   1
```

Comment: Inventory ID Name Description UniqueNameCount UniqueDESCCount
IN0001 Item 1 Desc 1 1 1
IN0002 Item 2 Desc 2 1 1
IN0003 Item 3 Desc 1 1 0
IN0004 Item 1 Desc 1 0 0
IN0005 Item 2 Desc 5 0 1
IN0006 Item 2 Desc 5 0 0
IN0007 Item 2 Desc 5 0 0
IN0008 Item 3 Desc 2 0 0
IN0009 Item 3 Desc 2 0 0
IN0010 Item 1 Desc 3 0 1

Comment: you should include that comment in your question

Comment: Can you add that data to the question instead? (Use edit.) Also add the expected result.

Comment: I am not able to add.. was getting some error so added in comment. Apology for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cebc7/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Inventory_ID, Name, Description ) AS
          SELECT 'IN0001',  'Item 1',  'Desc 1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0002',  'Item 2',  'Desc 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0003',  'Item 3',  'Desc 1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0004',  'Item 1',  'Desc 1' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0005',  'Item 2',  'Desc 5' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0006',  'Item 2',  'Desc 5' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0007',  'Item 2',  'Desc 5' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0008',  'Item 3',  'Desc 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0009',  'Item 3',  'Desc 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'IN0010',  'Item 1',  'Desc 3' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Inventory_ID,
       Name,
       Description,
       CASE
         WHEN LAG( Name ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Inventory_ID ) IS NULL
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS UniqueNameCount,
       CASE
         WHEN LAG( Description ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Description ORDER BY Inventory_ID ) IS NULL
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS UniqueDESCCount
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY Inventory_ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cebc7/1/0)**:

```
| INVENTORY_ID |   NAME | DESCRIPTION | UNIQUENAMECOUNT | UNIQUEDESCCOUNT |
|--------------|--------|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|
|       IN0001 | Item 1 |      Desc 1 |               1 |               1 |
|       IN0002 | Item 2 |      Desc 2 |               1 |               1 |
|       IN0003 | Item 3 |      Desc 1 |               1 |               0 |
|       IN0004 | Item 1 |      Desc 1 |               0 |               0 |
|       IN0005 | Item 2 |      Desc 5 |               0 |               1 |
|       IN0006 | Item 2 |      Desc 5 |               0 |               0 |
|       IN0007 | Item 2 |      Desc 5 |               0 |               0 |
|       IN0008 | Item 3 |      Desc 2 |               0 |               0 |
|       IN0009 | Item 3 |      Desc 2 |               0 |               0 |
|       IN0010 | Item 1 |      Desc 3 |               0 |               1 |
```

Comment: [LAG documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) - it splits the data up into groups based on the `PARTITION BY` clause and orders those groups internally by the `ORDER BY` clause and then `LAG` (with the default arguments) will look at the data in the row before the current row within the same partition - if it is `NULL` then either the data in the previous row was `NULL` or there was no previous data (i.e. it was the first row); since your data uses non-`NULL` values then it can be used to pick out the first row.

Comment: You could also use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function instead of `LAG()`: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cebc7/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use correlated sub-queries to find out if same name or description has been seen for a lower Inventory_ID.

```
select Inventory_ID, Name, Description,
       case when exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                         where t2.Name = t1.name
                           and t2.Inventory_ID < t1.Inventory_ID) then 0
            else 1
       end as UniqueNameCount,
       case when exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                         where t2.Description= t1.Description
                           and t2.Inventory_ID < t1.Inventory_ID) then 0
            else 1
       end as UniqueDESCCount
from tablename t1
```

Alternatively:

```
select t.Inventory_ID, t.Name, t.Description,
       coalesce(nt.cnt,0) as UniqueNameCount,
       coalesce(dt.cnt,0) as UniqueDescriptionCount
from tablename t
    left join (select MIN(Inventory_ID) Inventory_ID, Name, 1 as cnt
               from tablename group by Name) nt
        ON t.name = nt.name and t.Inventory_ID = nt.Inventory_ID
    left join (select MIN(Inventory_ID) Inventory_ID, Description, 1 as cnt
               from tablename group by Description) dt
        ON t.name = dt.Description and t.Inventory_ID = tt.Inventory_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. It is actually taking lot of time .. !!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some of them aren't that good at optimizing not exists sub-queries.

Comment: @Saurabh, untested but perhaps faster alternative added.